# Ajax .load() won't work when triggered initially

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have a simple tab system which I handle with the .load function to load the desired content. The problem is that the page itself which contains this tab system is a ajax loaded content. And for some reason the initial call of the tab function to display the initial tab content won't work. But after manually choosing a tab, the load function loads the content properly.

her some code to look at:

The tab handler:

```
function loadTab(tab) {
  $(".tab_a:eq("+otab+")").removeClass("tab_slc");
  $('#tab_content').hide();
  $('#tab_content').load("include/tab_downloadVersions.html .tab:eq("+tab+")");
  $(".tab_a:eq("+tab+")").addClass("tab_slc");
  $('#tab_content').fadeIn(function() {});
  otab = tab;
}
```

at the end I call `loadTab(tab);` and the thing should be initialized. but for some reason the content remains empty. As soon as you manually click on a tab (I have an on click function which calls `loadTab(tab)` everything starts working)

Because the code by itself works, I think the problem is caused by the other script which handles the page itself. It is also a .load function which loads the page, which loads this tab system.

So do multiple .loads don't like each other? and if so, what can I change?
Thanks in advance ;)

EDIT: I could't post the entire code for some reason, but if you go here you can see the site in action with all the scripts:
n.ethz.ch/student/lukal/paint.net

The tab system is on the download page.

EDIT:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Big Update**

So this is still the same issue but with a slight twist: I did what was recommended in the comments and put my secondary .load() call inside the success call of the first one.

```
$("#content").load("pages/contact #contentInside", function() {
        $("#OtherContent").load("include/info #OtherContentInside");
});
```

So this works.

But now I had the great idea to make a giant load function. It is a slightly better function than just the plain load, cause it does some fading and stuff. But now I have the same problem, but even more complicated. I created the load function as a "plugin" so the function itself is in a different script file and therefore I can't access the inside of the success function. I solved this problem with a `return $.ajax();` and a .done() call. The problem here is that there is some rare case where it just skips the secondary load function. So I am searching for a guaranteed way of controlling the order of the .load calls. Any idea?

The mock-up website is up to date with the new scripts if you wish to take a look. And people were complaining about potential virus spread from my link. For some reason I can't post long code snippets so the site is the best source I got to show everything. If you know a more trustworthy way to share my code please let me know.

Comment: When you call it initially, is it in the `$(document).ready()` handler?

Comment: if `#tab_content` doesn't exist when you call your load, you would  need to call it within success handler of the other ajax

Comment: yup. It was inside there, but still didn't work.

Comment: Interesting.. This actually worked. I put the function inside the .load function of the page handler, and the initialization worked!
But I am not really happy with this solution, because now it calls the function every time it loads a page, even though there may not be a tab system on the page..

Comment: I have a style for the selected(tab_slc) tab. tab is the current active tab and otab(old tab) is the one before to give it the default style so only one tab is highlighted.

Comment: You know no one is going to click a download link on a website they do not know.

Comment: Well if I was such a genius to make a virus I wouldn't be sitting here begging for help about javaScript right?
And its not a download link. It is a link to my mockup page where the tab system happens to be on the download page.

Comment: Does jquery accept `class` **"."** `.tab:eq("+tab+")"` as document fragment identifier ? See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Apparently it does. When you call the loadTab() function with a onclick event, everything works. It is the first pass, where it should display the initial tab, that is causing trouble.

Comment: updated OP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit disappointed by the system on stackoverflow. It seems like if you have not a high reputation level, no one gives a "S" about your questions. Well but at least some input was give, for which I am very thankful.
So by digging deeper into google I found out that the callback can be manually placed in the function where ever you like.

so if we have a function:

```
foo(lol, function() {
     //This after
});
```

this does stuff after foo() is done. But what if we have another function inside foo() which we also need to wait for:

```
function foo(lol) {
    bar(troll, function() {
       //This first
    });
}
```

The bar function is not relevant to the success call of foo. This causes the unpredictable outcome of calls.

The trick is to control when the success function of foo gets called.
If we add a parameter(callback) inside foo and call this "parameter" (callback();) inside the success call of bar, we can make sure the order is guaranteed.

And that's it:

```
function foo(lol, callback) {
   bar(troll, function() {
      //This first
      callback();   //<-This callback placement defines when it should be triggered
   });    
}

foo(lol, function() {
   //This after
});
```

We get:

```
//this first
//this after
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot see the rest of your code to tell where the initial call is being invoked from. A set up like the following should work:

```
$(function() {
    var tab = 0;
    loadTab( tab );
});
function loadTab(tab) {
  //WHAT IS otab???
  $(".tab_a:eq("+otab+")").removeClass("tab_slc"); //<<<==== otab
  $('#tab_content').hide();
  $('#tab_content').load("include/tab_downloadVersions.html .tab:eq("+tab+")");
  $(".tab_a:eq("+tab+")").addClass("tab_slc");
  $('#tab_content').fadeIn(function() {});
  otab = tab;
}
```

**Update**

**The reason it does not work initial is because `otab` is not defined the first time the function is called. You have initialized otab at the end of the function but you are using it at the beginning of the function.**

**UPDATE 2**

I have had a chance to look at your code and I just found out what the issues are:

1. You do not have DOM ready
2. You are not calling the function on page load.

The following version of your code should work -- try not to use global variable as you're doing with  `otab`. Since you're loading this script at the end of the page (an you are using event delegation) you may get away with DOM ready. Adding `.trigger('click')` or `click()` as indicated below should resolve the issue.

```
//Tab-loader
//Haeri Studios

var tab = 0;
var otab = tab;
var counter = 0;



//click detect
$(document).on('click', '.tab_a', function() {
    tab = counter == 0 ? tab : ($(this).attr('id'));
    loadTab(tab);
    counter++;
    return false; 
})
.trigger('click'); //<<<<<===== This will call the function when the page loads

//Tab setup
function loadTab(tab) {
    //Content Setup
    $(".tab_a:eq("+otab+")").removeClass("tab_slc");
    $('#tab_content').hide();
    $('#tab_content').load("include/tab_downloadVersions.html .tab:eq("+tab+")");
    $(".tab_a:eq("+tab+")").addClass("tab_slc");
    $('#tab_content').fadeIn(function() {});
    otab = tab;
}

//Initialize << WHAT ARE YOUR INTENTIONS HERE .. DO YOU REALLY NEED THIS PIECE?
$.ajax({success: function() {
    loadTab(tab);
}});
```

Comment: otab is also initialized.
var tab = 0;
var otab = tab;

Comment: That is at the end of the function. Yet you're using it on the first line of the function. Can you post in the question the rest or your JS together with the relevant HTML.

Comment: I have updated OP so you can see the full code on the webpage

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but like I said. The code is fine. otab is also initialized at the beginning. I tested this code snipped and it worked like it should. It is the combination of packing a .load function into another .load function(the page loader) that is causing problems.

Comment: I just looked at your code and you're missing `DOM READY`. I'll update my code momentarily.

Comment: I have updated my code as well. I don't call loadTab() in the same script anymore. I have created a new function which gets called after a successful ajax page load. This then decides weather it is necessary to load the tab system. So it is working now. But if you have something more elegant I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: .trigger('click'); as it is gives me an syntax error. I added $('.tab_a:eq(1)').trigger('click'); but still no luck. Anyway I think I am going to leave it how it is. The new bridge function I added is actually very helpful for future js code which may use .load function.

Comment: Glad it is working. However, I am not able to make any suggestions on something I can't see. I realize that we're not reading from the same script.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I was experimenting on the live server. But I havn't changed anything anymore so if you can clear your cash, you should see the latest (working) version ;)

Comment: There're 3 new changes that should fix the syntax error. (1). `var counter = 0;` (2). `tab = counter == 0 ? tab : ($(this).attr('id'));` and (3). `ounter++;`

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer to this problem was to call the loadTab function inside the success call of the page load function, like charlietfl pointed out. But the problem is that there is no need to call the tabloader every time a new page gets called. So I would rather not have a rare call in every page setup function.